# Loop through an array ignores \n

Tags: json, perl

@edit
Below is the JSON getting saved as $content

```
[
    {
        "date_created": 1234,
        "fingerprint_hash": null,
        "address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
        "name": null,
        "manufacturer": "xxx",
        "date_updated": 1234,
        "active": true,
        "date_last_active": 1234,
        "mac_group_info": {
            "name": null,
            "id": 0,
            "remarks": null
        },
        "id": 1234,
        "remarks": null,
        "arp_mapping_info": [
            {
                "ip_info": {
                    "date_changed": 1234,
                    "date_last_kerberos_login": null,
                    "dns_name": "xxxx",
                    "id": 6,
                    "remarks": null,
                    "date_created": 1234,
                    "kerberos_user_name": null,
                    "ip_group_info": {
                        "remarks": null,
                        "id": 0,
                        "name": null
                    },
                    "address": "x.x.x.x"
                },
                "interface_info": [
                    {
                        "link": "on",
                        "name": "x",
                        "discovery_info": null,
                        "speed": 1234,
                        "host_info": {
                            "backup_sensor_id": 0,
                            "type": "xxxx",
                            "radius_coa_flags": null,
                            "moment": 1,
                            "name": null,
                            "host_group_info": {
                                "name": null,
                                "id": 0,
                                "remarks": null
                            },
                            "interface_mib": "D",
                            "uplink_count": 1,
                            "sensor_info": {
                                "id": 1,
                                "os_version": "xxxx",
                                "architecture": "xxxx",
                                "remarks": null,
                                "last_contact": "xxxx",
                                "queue": 0,
                                "address": "x.x.xx",
                                "status": "active",
                                "os_name": "linux",
                                "name": "xxxx",
                                "version": "x.x.x-x"
                            },
                            "mode": "xx",
                            "address": "x.x.x.x",
                            "radius_secret": null,
                            "arp_mib": "2",
                            "cam_count": 1,
                            "discovery2_mib": "C",
                            "discovery1_mib": "3",
                            "radius_coa_port": null,
                            "radius_requests_count": 0,
                            "vlan_count": 1,
                            "access_to_port": 1,
                            "vlan_mib": "C",
                            "interval": 1,
                            "snmp_traps_community": null,
                            "engine_mode": "dynamic",
                            "manufacturer": "ciscoSystems",
                            "engine_id": null,
                            "snmp_traps_version": "1",
                            "mib_options": null,
                            "remarks": null,
                            "snmp_write_version": "2c",
                            "snmp_write_community": "private",
                            "access_to_cam": 1,
                            "status": "ok",
                            "access_to_cto": 1,
                            "access_to_interface": 1,
                            "snmp_read_version": "1",
                            "snmp_read_community": "public",
                            "id": 1,
                            "cam_mib": "C",
                            "arp_count": 1,
                            "access_to_arp": 1,
                            "port_count": 1,
                            "main_sensor_id": 1
                        },
                        "status": "on",
                        "index": 1,
                        "protocols": [
                            "ARP",
                            "NDP"
                        ],
                        "id": 1,
                        "remarks": null,
                        "sniffer_mode": null
                    }
                ],
                "host_id": 1
            }
        ],
        "cam_mapping_info": []
    }
]
```

Thats my code:

```
foreach ($content){
    $content =~ s/\[/\[\n\t/g;
    $content =~ s/{/{\n\t/g;
    $content =~ s/\]/\n\]/g;
    $content =~ s/}/}\n/g;
    $content =~ s/,/\n\t/g;
print $content;
}
```

Todo: get the same output as the JSON above but with a perl skript runing it **withouth any modules**, normaly we use postman for it. As I asked my "couch" for help he only said: just learn to programm. Yeah...

The output I get with my regex is almost the solution. It just stops tabing after the first tab, doent repeat it on another opening bracket.

Comment: That is not how you use `until`... `until` is just a negated `while` loop. You just avoid getting an endless loop there because you misunderstood how your `eq` statement work (`|| "]"` is always true).

Comment: You should show how you assign data to `$data`. If you want us to help you with that.

Comment: @TLP done some additing going a bit deeper into the detail. I have no problem with assigning data to variables, the real struggle is procesing of the data.

Comment: Apparently you do have a problem, since you think `$data` is an array. I've told you what I need, I'm experienced in helping beginners solve problems. If you don't want to provide that, that is fine, but then I don't think you will get help by anyone. If your boss says you have to parse JSON with regex, you have my sympathies. Regex is unlikely to be a good solution as JSON is complex. You would have to provide test cases with exact input and expected output.

Comment: If this is for human readable format, I'm sure there is some code already written to achieve that: JSON to Human readable. And if your boss does not allow "modules", then take the code out of those modules and use them in your own program file. But better solution is to replace the boss. Failing that, there are plenty of questions giving advice to people who "cant install modules". It is a common mistake people make that is easily remedied.

Comment: @TLP Uploaded the input JSON. And as I belive im pretty near solving the problem..

Comment: If you really can't use modules, just download the PP version of YAML and bundle it with your program. JSON::PP is already core and comes with your Perl installation.

Comment: @TLP Im forced to use regex, I had one working solution using modules but they said its too easy. Make one without any.  And any question I have is meet with just google it. Guess its time to change the employer

Comment: What do you mean "too easy"? Are they trying to make it harder for you?

Comment: They said its good to learn programming and understand the process. And kind off any solution I could find on google uses modules. heh

Comment: That sounds like they are not interested in solving the problem, just interested in making work for you. I'm afraid I can't help you make a regex that can balance nested braces, including quoted strings, that is beyond my powers. If you ask here on Stackoverflow, I'm sure most people would say that parsing JSON with regex is the wrong way to do it. Good luck though, that boss seems to be maybe not the best one.

Comment: Also, to "learn programming", you don't start with a task as hard as this one. This is advanced level programming if you forbid modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked a coworker for help and he has just writen it in 5 minutes without big thinking...

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $content = #JSON#
my @arr = split //, $content;
my $length = scalar @arr;
my $tabcounter = 0;
for (my $i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {

   print $arr[$i];
   if ( $arr[$i] eq '[' || $arr[$i] eq ']' || $arr[$i] eq '{' || $arr[$i] eq '}' || $arr[$i] eq ',') {
        print "\n";
        if ( $arr[$i] eq '[' || $arr[$i] eq '{' ) {
            $tabcounter++;
        }
        if ( $arr[$i] eq '}' || $arr[$i] eq ']' ) {
            $tabcounter--;
        }
        for (my $j=0; $j < $tabcounter; $j++) {
            print "\t";
        }
   }
}
```

So if anyone has to read and print out of a JSON file without any modules, here is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

`$line eq "{" || "["` is interpreted as

```
(($line eq '{') or '[')
```

(as [Deparse](https://p3rl.org/B::Deparse) would show you). Use

```
$line eq '{' || $line eq '['
```

Moreover, `$data` is a scalar variable, i.e. it contains a single value. Iterating over it makes just a single step.

Normally, you'd iterate over an array:

```
foreach my $line (@lines)
```

or maybe an array reference:

```
foreach my $line (@$data)
```

or whatever else

```
foreach my $line ($line1, $line2, @rest_of_lines)
# or
foreach my $line (split /\n/, $message)
```

Comment: When using just @data I get the same output as $data, meaning keeps ignoring the \n

when runing foreach my $line (@$data) he spits on me with "Can't use string as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use"

Comment: @Jakoby The point is that `foreach my $line($data)` is wrong because it's the same as `my $line = $data;`, and that's obviously not what you want. Without more info, it's not clear what you have/want. choroba provided solutions and when to use them. But using code meant for when you have `@data` is obviously not going to work if you don't have a variable named `@data`. And using code meant for when `$data` is a reference to an array is obviously not going to work if you don't have a reference to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`YAML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML) module, you can get a quick human readable format. I'm sure there are other and/or better ways to format your text, but this is one example. The benefit here is that you can transform a JSON data structure (using [`JSON::PP`](https://perldoc.perl.org/JSON::PP), a core Perl module that comes pre-installed) into a Perl data structure and then into a YAML structure that you can print easily. I did this with a few lines of code and a few modules, using some sample JSON data.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::PP;
use YAML;

my $text = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $json = decode_json($text);
print Dump $json;

__DATA__
{
    "ITEM":[
        {
            "-itemID": "1000000" ,
            "-itemName": "DisneyJuniorLA" ,
            "-thumbUrl": "" ,
            "-packageID": "1" ,
            "-itemPrice": "0" ,
            "-isLock": "true"
        },
        {
            "-itemID": "1000001" ,
            "-itemName": "31 minutos" ,
            "-thumbUrl": "" ,
            "-packageID": "1" ,
            "-itemPrice": "0" ,
            "-isLock": "true"
        },
        {
            "-itemID": "1000002" ,
            "-itemName": "Plaza SÚsamo" ,
            "-thumbUrl": "" ,
            "-packageID": "1" ,
            "-itemPrice": "0" ,
            "-isLock": "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

Output:

```
---
ITEM:
  - -isLock: true
    -itemID: 1000000
    -itemName: DisneyJuniorLA
    -itemPrice: 0
    -packageID: 1
    -thumbUrl: ''
  - -isLock: true
    -itemID: 1000001
    -itemName: 31 minutos
    -itemPrice: 0
    -packageID: 1
    -thumbUrl: ''
  - -isLock: true
    -itemID: 1000002
    -itemName: Plaza S┌samo
    -itemPrice: 0
    -packageID: 1
    -thumbUrl: ''
```

EDIT: With the new json data, I get this output:

```
- active: !!perl/scalar:JSON::PP::Boolean 1
  address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
  arp_mapping_info:
    - host_id: 1
      interface_info:
        - discovery_info: ~
          host_info:
            access_to_arp: 1
            access_to_cam: 1
            access_to_cto: 1
            access_to_interface: 1
            access_to_port: 1
            address: x.x.x.x
            arp_count: 1
            arp_mib: 2
            backup_sensor_id: 0
            cam_count: 1
            cam_mib: C
            discovery1_mib: 3
            discovery2_mib: C
            engine_id: ~
            engine_mode: dynamic
            host_group_info:
              id: 0
              name: ~
              remarks: ~
            id: 1
            interface_mib: D
            interval: 1
            main_sensor_id: 1
            manufacturer: ciscoSystems
            mib_options: ~
            mode: xx
            moment: 1
            name: ~
            port_count: 1
            radius_coa_flags: ~
            radius_coa_port: ~
            radius_requests_count: 0
            radius_secret: ~
            remarks: ~
            sensor_info:
              address: x.x.xx
              architecture: xxxx
              id: 1
              last_contact: xxxx
              name: xxxx
              os_name: linux
              os_version: xxxx
              queue: 0
              remarks: ~
              status: active
              version: x.x.x-x
            snmp_read_community: public
            snmp_read_version: 1
            snmp_traps_community: ~
            snmp_traps_version: 1
            snmp_write_community: private
            snmp_write_version: 2c
            status: ok
            type: xxxx
            uplink_count: 1
            vlan_count: 1
            vlan_mib: C
          id: 1
          index: 1
          link: on
          name: x
          protocols:
            - ARP
            - NDP
          remarks: ~
          sniffer_mode: ~
          speed: 1234
          status: on
      ip_info:
        address: x.x.x.x
        date_changed: 1234
        date_created: 1234
        date_last_kerberos_login: ~
        dns_name: xxxx
        id: 6
        ip_group_info:
          id: 0
          name: ~
          remarks: ~
        kerberos_user_name: ~
        remarks: ~
  cam_mapping_info: []
  date_created: 1234
  date_last_active: 1234
  date_updated: 1234
  fingerprint_hash: ~
  id: 1234
  mac_group_info:
    id: 0
    name: ~
    remarks: ~
  manufacturer: xxx
  name: ~
  remarks: ~
```